# $f(x) = \arctan(\frac{1+x}{1-x})$ continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I would like to study the continuity of the function : 
$$\text{when } x \ne 1, f(x) = \arctan\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right) \text{ and } f(1) =-\pi/2$$

Here is what I've done so far :

We know that the function $x \rightarrow \arctan(x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. We also know that the function $x \rightarrow \frac{1+x}{1-x}$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R} - \{1\}$.
Because the composition of two continuous function is continuous we can now say that : $\arctan(\frac{1+x}{1-x})$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}-\{1\}$.

Yet I don't know how to proove that this function is yes or no continuous on $\mathbb{R}.$

Comment: Can you compute $\lim_{x \to 1} f(x)$? What does that tell you?

Comment: @MartinR I think you mean $x \to 1$.

Comment: Look what happens when $x \to 1^+$ and when $x \to 1^-$

Comment: @Lucas why on $1^{+}$ and on $1^{-}$ and not only on $1$ ?

Comment: You have to distinguish both cases because the function has a different behaviour (since $1/0^+ = +\infty$ and $1/0^- = -\infty$). It suffices to show there is a problem in one of the two cases to conclude it is not continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is NOT continuous because
$$
\lim_{x\to 1^{-}}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 1^{-}}\arctan\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}\ne -\frac{\pi}{2}.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Yet I don't understand why you compute the limit on $1^{-}$ and not on $1$ ? Also how did you get that result ?

Comment: @Salutsalut1 It’s because to conclude about continuity, we have to check the limit from both sides. We can already see they disagree. If you need to be more rigorous, apply this same technique for $1^+$. Here, $\lim_{x\to1}$ does not exist.